# How to change generalised coordinates in a Lagrangian without inverting the coordinate transformation?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, coordinate-systems

Given a Lagrangian using the standard cartesian coordinates.
$$ \mathcal{L} = \frac{1}{2}m(\dot{x}^2 + \dot{y}^2) - \frac{1}{2}k(x^2 + y^2) $$

How to move to the hyperbolic coordinates given as
$$2 x y = \mu $$
$$ x^2 - y^2 = \lambda $$

One way is to invert the expression of the hyperbolic coordinates and express $x$ and $y $ as a function of $\mu$ and $\lambda$ and substitute it into the lagrangian.

Is there a more direct method which does not involve inverting the function?

Comment: You can't invert the map as $(x,y)$ and $(-x-y)$ are different points, but have the same values of $\mu$, $\lambda$.

Comment: @mikestone I get that, but the point is I wish to get to equation 2.25 without inverting the map (whichever domain it maybe invertible in) http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/dynamics.html

Comment: I can’t think of anything more direct than david’s approach here

Answer (score 1):

What you propose is needlessly busy, as it forfeits the visible symmetries of the system, notably in its quadratic forms.

Instead, note that, in polar coordinates,
$$
x=r\cos\theta, \qquad y= r\sin\theta,~~\leadsto \\
x^2+y^2= r^2,  \qquad\dot{x}^2+ \dot{y}^2 =\dot{ r}^2 + r^2 \dot {\theta}^2,
$$
and further,
$$
\mu= r^2 \sin 2\theta ,  \qquad \lambda = r^2 \cos 2\theta, ~~\leadsto \\
\lambda^2 + \mu^2 = (r^2)^2,  \qquad \dot{\lambda}^2+ \dot{\mu}^2= 4r^2
(\dot{ r}^2 + r^2 \dot {\theta}^2)= 4\sqrt{\lambda^2 + \mu^2 } ~~(\dot{ r}^2 + r^2 \dot {\theta}^2). 
$$
Behold! The trig functions are gone.

- Inspection of the two cases  predictably leads to the hyper-symmetric lagrangean,
  $$
  {m\over 2} \frac{ \dot{\lambda}^2+ \dot{\mu}^2}{4\sqrt{\lambda^2 + \mu^2 }} - {k\over 2}\left (\sqrt{\lambda^2 + \mu^2 }\right).
  $$

Answer (score 0):

Starting with hyperbolic coordinates

$$g1:=2\,x\,y=\mu\\
g2:=x^2-y^2=\lambda$$

from here with $~x=r\cos(\phi)~,y=r\sin(\phi)~$

$$g1:=r^2\,\sin(2\phi)=\mu\\
g2:=r^2\cos(2\phi)=\lambda$$

solve those two equations for $~r~,\phi~$ you obtain

$$\phi=\frac 12\arctan\left(\frac \mu\lambda\right)\tag 1$$
$$r=\pm\,(\mu^2+\lambda^2)^{1/4}
\tag 2$$

the lagrangian with polar coordinates is

$$\cal L=\frac m2 (\dot r^2+r^2\dot\phi^2)-\frac k2 r^2$$

with equations $~(1)~,(2)$

$$\cal L=\frac 18\frac{m}{\sqrt{\mu^2+\lambda^2}}
\,(\dot\mu^2+\dot\lambda^2)-\frac k2\,\sqrt{\mu^2+\lambda^2}$$

---

$$\dot r=\frac 12\,{\frac {\mu\,\dot\mu +\lambda\,\dot\lambda }{ \left( {\mu}^{2}+{\lambda
}^{2} \right) ^{3/4}}}$$

$$\dot\phi=\frac 12\,{\frac {\lambda\,\dot\mu -\mu\,\dot\lambda }{{\mu}^{2}+{\lambda}^{2}}}$$